# Noticeable lag while sculpting

Tags: sculpting, sculpt

So I tried to sculpt on a reasonably high poly model as shown below. Earlier the model was low poly and only the necessary loops to maintain the overall shape.

[image]

In both instances, while making fast strokes with dyntopo active at various settings, blender lags and makes rough, angled strokes although I intend to make smooth, curved strokes, as shown below.

[image]

I figure it maybe a problem with the configuration of my rig, although i maybe wrong.

My rig :

CPU : AMD Ryzen 5 1600

RAM : Corsair DDR4 16 GB 3000MHz

GPU : AMD Sapphire RX 580 8GB

Motherboard : ASUS EX-A320M

Comment: so if you use Dyntopo, why did you feel the need to subdivide your mesh? Dyntopo is precisely made to avoid subdivisions. Also are you sure your subdivision is still low? It looks very dense around the edges... maybe check the amount of vertices

Comment: @moonboots well first I tried without the subdivs, it was lagging right off the bat, I assumed that blender couldn't process where to add the dyntopo and connect it simultaneously, so I added subdivisons to test if that was the case which kinda seemed like it got fixed for the moment, but later returned as seen above. Yes in retrospect the are a bit too much, but this is a test model so it's not a problem.